# Session control vue.js

Tags: php, api, vue.js

this is my first post. I am doing my final project of course. I'm going to do the client part with Vue.js and the server part with php through an API. My question is how you would control the sessions. I had planned to save a user id in a Cookie and then validate it in each API call. But I don't know if it is the safest and most efficient. Greetings and thank you.

Comment: Json Web Tokens and localstorage. See https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thank you. I am going to study it and implement it in my project